# How can I remove the space between tab widget?

Tags: android, tabs, android-2.3-gingerbread

I would like to remove the spacing between tabwidgets. By default there is around 1px spacings between tabs. I know some apps like foursquare or posterous are able to remove it. How is the code to do this would look like? I am using 2.3 API.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is "the spacing between tabwidgets"?

Answer (score 6):

You can use getTabHost().getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.empty_divider) method,
where R.drawable.empty_divider simple shape with 0px size, such as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line" >
    <size
        android:width="0px"
        android:color="@android:color/black"
        android:dashWidth="0px"
        android:dashGap="0px" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. Really appreciate it. I saved this XML as empty_divider.xml under drawable folders. But it still doesn't work when I called it as you explained. Am I missing something?

Comment: for some reasons StackOverflow's editer cutted last closing tag 
take a look at this manual page 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Answer (score 5):

TabWidget android:showDividers="none"

Comment: Hi Shuidi, Welcome to StackOverflow, It will be more helpful for users if you can give them a little more description , Thank you for your answer..

Answer (score 4):

If your build target is Honeycomb onwards, you may use the following code.

```
if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    tabHost.getTabWidget().setShowDividers(LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_NONE);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution...I was facing a similar issue with ICS devices and your solution worked perfectly well for me.

Answer (score 3):

I solve this same problem with this line of code:

```
 tabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add android:showDividers="none" to Layout XML

```
<TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="none" />
```